# What is the difference between MCMC and Gauss-Legendre quadrature for integration? Can one substitute the other?

Tags: numerical-integration

Both MCMC and Legendre quadrature are numerical methods for integration.

**Method 1: MCMC**
    $$E[g(X)] = \int f(x) g(x) \, dx$$

**Method 2: Gauss-Legendre quadrature**
    $$\int_{0.5}^{1.5} e^x \cos x \, dx$$
    $$= \sum_{i=1}^{k} c_i\cdot f(x_i)$$
where $f(x)=e^x \cos x, \text{ with weights } c_i, \text{ and nods } x_i$.

**Example: Gauss-Legendre** (requested in comments)

Suppose I want to integrate at 3 points on, $f(x) = e^x \cos x$

3 Nods are: $x_i =[0.7746, 0, -0.7746]$
3 Weights are: $w_i = [0.5556, 0.8888888888888888, 0.5556]$

Thus,
    $$\int_{0.5}^{1.5} e^x \cos x \, dx = \sum_{i=1}^{3} c_i\cdot f(x_i)=1.275$$

You can also refer here: https://math.okstate.edu/people/yqwang/teaching/math4513_fall14/Notes/gaussian.pdf

So, which method to use to integrate out $\theta$?
    $$f(x) = \int f(x,\theta) p(\theta) \, d\theta$$

**My goal is to calculate the marginal distribution.**  I am using Gauss-Legendre, but can I also use MCMC?  What's the difference?  I am a bit confused.

Comment: I am not familiar with Gauss- Legendre quadrature. So what exactly are the $x_i$s?

Comment: @Greenparker: usually these are zeros of the interpolating family.

Comment: @AlexR. I thought $c_i$s are the weights?

Comment: Hi, I have updated the question with an example of Gauss-Legendre quadrature.

Comment: You shouldn't use the same symbol, the lower-case $x$, to refer both to the random variable and to the variable of integration, in things like $$ \operatorname{E}(g(X)) = \int f(x)g(x)\,dx $$ (where, as you see, I wrote capital $X$ for the random variable and lower-case $x$ for the variable of integration. Without distinguishing those two things, how would you understand something like $F(x) = \Pr(X\le x)$, or the difference between $F_X(3.5)$ and $F_Y(3.5)$, when those would be $F_X(x)$ and $F_Y(x)$ when $x=3.5$? $\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy I am not finding the expectation, I am marginalizing over a joint density $f(x, \theta)$, with parameter $\theta$ not fixed.

Comment: @user13985 : I don't know the relevance of that to what I said.  At any rate I edited the question to use proper notation. $\qquad$

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that MCMC is stochastic whereas quadrature methods are deterministic. The latter are defined by picking weights and interpolation points, that are usually determined by the zeros of the family of orthogonal polynomials you choose. Quadrature methods are generally superior to simpler numerical integration schemes like the trapezoid rule, in that they give higher accuracy for less computation.

However quadrature methods start to fail very badly in high dimensions because of the vast number of points you need to interpolate at, along with the fact that quadrature methods are blind to large variations in your function. As well quadrature methods do not work well with functions that are difficult to approximate with polynomials. With VEGAS monte carlo methods, you usually try to (randomly) pick areas where your function has larger values, which causes them to be more efficient than quadrature methods in a number of (ideal) situations.

Comment: For MCMC, can you integrate out variables?  I only remember I can get random samples, and then calculate mean and variance.

Comment: WIth your updated question, are you basically asking if MCMC can return what looks to be a *function* of $x$?

Comment: Yes, I am calculating the marginal distribution: $f(x) = \int f(x,\theta) p(\theta) d\theta$

Comment: Then the answer is likely no, unless you either do repeated sampling for a grid of points $x$, or you make a variational assumption, for example by assuming $f(x,\theta)=g(x)h(\theta)$. The same applies to quadrature methods.

Comment: I thought MCMC is a numerical integration method, what I am missing here?  And marginal distribution is an integration of the joint distribution.

Comment: OK, you need to define *exactly* what your $f(x,y)$ is then. It's a joint distribution?

Comment: Yes, $f(x, y)$ is a joint distribution.

Comment: Are you doing some kind of machine learning problem? Could you elaborate on the exact form of $f(x,y)$ and $p$?

Comment: Sure, say in Bayesian statistics likelihood function is $f(x, \theta)$, prior is $p(\theta)$.  I want to know if I can use quadrature for this.

Comment: @user13985: Take a look at this: http://www.cedar.buffalo.edu/~srihari/CSE574/Chap3/EvidenceApproximation.pdf

Comment: So, can MCMC do variable marginalization?  Say integrating out $\theta$ in joint density $f(x, \theta)$?